# Programmatically call rawQuery when app starts

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

We have these two classes MainActivity and a DBHelper

The `DBHelper` creates the Database and two Tables one table, `masterPW`, which will only have one row and two columns, `ID` and `ColPW`. This table will only contain one record once created and data is inserted.

The column `ColPW` will be empty or null when the app starts
the first time.

We would like to call a `rawQuery` programmatically when the app starts and set the value of the `ColPW` column to a `String`.

If the string variable is null or empty the `MainActivity` displays
two `EditText` fields and the SAVE button. If the string variable obtains 
data from the `ColPW` column. The MainActivity will only display one
EditText field and the ENTER button.

Being real new to Android I am at a loss here how to make the 
app programmatically call the `rawQuery`. Where do I place the `rawQuery`?

If the result of the query is in the `DBHelper` Class, how to send the
result to the `MainActivity`? Intents, Global singleton Class, or
use a Model Class with getters and setters and Adapter Class?

I have written this with DerbyDB and JavaFX, but I could open
and create the table query the table all in the same Class

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btnSave;
        Button btnEnter;
        TextView tvPW;
        TextView tvCPW;
        EditText etPW;
        EditText etCPW;
        int x = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
            tvPW = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tvPW );
            tvCPW = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tvCPW );
            etPW = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.etPW );
            etCPW = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.etCPW );

            btnEnter = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnEnter );
            btnSave = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnSave );
            addListenerOnButtonSave();

            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper( this );
            String str = dbHelper.getCol_PW();
            if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println( "I am null" );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "I am NOT NULL" );
            }
        }

        private void addListenerOnButtonSave() {
        btnSave.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       if (x == 1) {
       btnSave.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
       btnEnter.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
       tvCPW.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
       etCPW.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
       etPW.requestFocus();
       setTitle( "Enter Password" );

       }

       }
       } );
       }
    }
    import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "PassWord";
    public static final Integer DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "masterPW";
    public static final String Col_ID = "ID";
    public static final String Col_MPW = "mpw";

    private static final String MAKE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + Col_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Col_MPW + " TEXT" + ")";

    SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( MAKE_TABLE );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL(MAKE_TABLE);
    }

    public String getCol_PW(){
        String str = null;
        String q = "SELECT mpw FROM masterPW";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_MPW));
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: One getter - inside DBHelper. That is really all you need. Then, make an instance of `DBHelper` inside `onCreate` of the Activity. No need for singletons. SQLite doesn't deal with Intent. You are welcome to create a Model for some ORM purpose, but that isn't necessary for your purpose here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity onCreate try to do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    String str = dbHelper.getColPW();
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()){
        //display 2 edittext
    } else {
        //display 1 edittext
    }

}
```

In DBHelper.java:

```
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
public String getColPW(){
    String str = null;
    myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select " + COL_MPW + " from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_MPW));
    }
    return str;
}
```

If you have questions, please ask in comments.

Comment: so I still create my Database and Table in the DBHelper Class? and your line of code in MainActivity DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this) and the String str = dbHelper.getColPW(); will execute the method in  DBHelper Class I will give this a try and up vote if this works My other concern here is this Thread Save ?

Comment: Can you post your DBHelper class?

Comment: should be `"select mpw"` or `"select " + DBHelper.Col_MPW + " from ..."`

Comment: What error code? And post please your updated DBHelper and MainActivity too.

Comment: db variable is probably null, I think you have to initialize it before calling rawQuery() like db = getWritableDatabase(). Please look at updated code, as on example.

Comment: @pavel That was it Code works but my question still stands is this Thread SAFE making calls from the Main Activity Thanks For Your Help IF anyone is looking at this code please note I named my database this way in DBHelper SQLiteDatabase db;

Comment: Yes, this is thread safe, because we are connecting database synchronosely, i.e. in one thread.

Comment: @pavel I have been reading as much as I can. Could you explain how we know this thread safe I understand SYNCHRONOUSLY If I add the SAVE passwords to the MainActivity will this become an issue after password is confirmed I plan to go to new Activity and enter new data to a different TABLE thought about CursorLoader and ContentProvider with a model class

Comment: All events that you described in comment are happening in one thread - main thread, or it called also UI thread, because we can not access UI from background, i.e. other threads. Local database access also happening in same thread. You can read more about threads here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html?hl=ru. Also I would recommend try out AsyncTask.